# JVM 8 Thread stack size

Tags: java, jvm

Based on java 8 core dump, i am seeing the below output for each thread

`thread: 29 - stack range: 0x7f135570b000-0x7f135c373000, size: 111008 kB`

java 8 thread stack size on 64bit VM is 1028 Kb, how is the above thread showing stack size of 111008 kB?

Comment: Where do you see this output?

Comment: @apangin the jvm generated a core dump, which was processed by a tool called dynatrace and it is showing the above output

Comment: This seems to be a bug of dynatrace then. It probably takes the nearest contiguous range of virtual address space that contains not only the thread stack, but also other parts of the process' memory.